# Include header and footer to MS Word file through PHP

Tags: php

```
header('Content-Type: application/ms word');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = filename.docx");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
```

I used the above code to download a word file with some data from database.

Now, I want to add a logo and name of the company, page number on each and every page of my file. Ηow should i do it?

Comment: i tried get the line number of file. but it failed.

Comment: Are you wanting to modify the word document itself?

Comment: Please include the code you tried to use that didn't work.

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

Comment: <?php

$file = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/TESTDATA/wordfilename.docx", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$f=0;

//Output a line of the file until the end is reached

while(!feof($file))

  {
   fgets($file). "<br>";
   $f++;
  }
fclose($file);
echo $f;
?>
i just tried to make count of the line to an already created file. just for sample. i have only 4 month exp in this field

Comment: @adamdunson. i want to download my data  file from database along with the header in all page. at the first time itself

Comment: @FoolishSeth: i downloaded PHPdocX free version and i am using xampp for generating php code. how should i do this. i got tip from PHPdocX documentation but i am confused. can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How long did you use Google for?

Now I'm not sure about [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/), but [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) is still quite in its infancy but I think it should be able to handle your problem.

Also, if their github page doesn't work, try their [codeplex](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) page. I'm not quite sure which one of their code base is more up to date/work on (I'm fairly sure it's github though).

Comment: i downloaded PHPdocX free version and i am using xampp for generating php code. how should i do this. i got tip from PHPdocX documentation but i am confused. can anyone please help me.